# Android Studio include maven artifact in APK (gradle)

Tags: android-studio, gradle, noclassdeffounderror, artifact

I have an Android project that requires the [Jsoup library](http://jsoup.org). I've tried everything I can think of to get the jar shaded into the APK.. I just can't get it working. Logcat tells me:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jsoup.Jsoup

Does anyone know how to include/shade a maven artifact into an APK with Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer. The trick is to append ":sources". See an example here: http://www.alonsoruibal.com/my-gradle-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: Also, in settings.gradle I added jsoup, so it looks similar to this:
include ':PSMonitor', 'org.jsoup:jsoup'

Comment: I seem to have the [same Gradle problem with the Jackson library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245855/noclassdeffounderror-using-jackson-2-2-x-on-android-with-gradle). I would be happy if you can take a look at my question. I appended `:sources` in `build.gradle` and `'com.fasterxml.jackson.core'` in `settings.gradle` - same error message though.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same type of error every time someone else adds a library with Gradle. Build is usually successful but app crashes when it tries to use the new library. Running task `clean` with Gradle helps.