# NoClassDefFoundError using Jackson 2.2.x on Android with Gradle

Tags: android, json, jackson, gradle, build.gradle

For my Android project I set up Gradle with [Jackson 2.2.x](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) as follows:

```
// build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.+'
}
```

I simply use the `ObjectMapper` here:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

// ...

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
try {
    Content content = objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, Content.class);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I run `gradle installDebug` and launch the relevant part of the application it crashes:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

---

### Thoughts:

- I noticed that in the error message `com.fasterxml.jackson...` is mentioned while `com.fasterxml.jackson.core` is defined in `build.gradle`. Is there a mismatch causing the problem?
- I temporarily moved the `dependencies` block into the `android` block since I [found other `build.gradle` configurations](https://github.com/ligi/FAST/blob/4.3/app/build.gradle) structured this way. However it seems to make no difference.

Comment: Can you unzip the APK and run `dexdump classes.dex | grep 'Class descriptor'` and see if Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper ?

Comment: @Ethan No, the class descriptor for `ObjectMapper` is **not** contained in the `classes.dex` of `Foobar-debug-unaligned.apk`.

Comment: can you do a `gradle clean installDebug`, see if that fails, if it does post the output of `gradle dependencies`

Comment: @Ethan Found the same hint [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18786851/356895), simultaneously. Running `gradle clean` is the solution to the problem. Please extract your comment into an answer. Maybe combine both comments since both were helpful!

Comment: good to hear that worked for you. Comments extracted.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you again. This was eaten a lot of my time. Have a nice week.

Comment: I have some thoughts on your thoughts. Gradle will pull in any dependency needed by your defined dependencies. You can see this by running `gradle dependencies`. The top level of the graph is your dependencies that are defined, anything lower that that (indented) are the 'transient' dependencies. There are three phases on setting up the gradle script. Link here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gradle and Android don't always place nicely with dependencies(yet). Running

```
 gradle clean
```

seems to fix most problems for me.

*Note:* If that didn't work, you can run

```
dexdump classes.dex | grep 'Class descriptor'
```

on the classes.dex file in the APK. That will check to see if the class is included in the `classes.dex` file. (Sometimes it's useful if you want to double check whats going on).

Comment: +1 for clean, got similar issue few days back when test been failing because gradle did not assesd situation correctly. Clean FTW

Answer (score 3):

## Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.test"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'  `enter code here`
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind :2.5.3'

}
```

Add permission and dependency into you Gradle and then build gradle you will get Object wrapper class